# Vscode + PHP : how to align code by arrow operator?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm using extension PHP Intelephense. When I save the file the code is like:

[image]

But I want the code to be like this when saving:

[image]

What extensions or settings can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer), a tool that automatically formats your code. It comes with a special fixer, called `binary_operator_spaces`, that aligns operators. You can find more details about it [here](https://mlocati.github.io/php-cs-fixer-configurator/#version:3.46%7Cfixer:binary_operator_spaces), including some examples, on how to use it (#8 is closest to your use case).

Note however, that it does not align the keys of the array to the right, they remain left aligned. As far as I know the PHP-CS-Fixer does not support that.

There also exists a [VS Code extension](https://github.com/junstyle/vscode-php-cs-fixer), that provides a command to run the PHP-CS-Fixer from inside VS Code. I never used it, so you will have to evaluate the extension yourself.